# why is 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 divided by 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 not equal to 1000 in Java?

Tags: java, puzzle, math

why is 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 divided by 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 not equal to 1000 in Java?

Comment: Because Java stretches in east-west direction, so the day is a bit longer than 86400000000 microseconds :-)

Comment: I think for this question to make sense it has to specify that it means int's and not long's.  without displaying actual code or specifying, the question is ambiguous.  this is the kind of question I hated on tests in school - am i supposed to answer "it *does* equal 1000" (correct, if assuming longs) or am i supposed to guess that the prof meant to imply that everything was being done as ints, and therefore mention overflow?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Because the multiplication overflows 32 bit integers. In 64 bits it's okay:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int intProduct = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
        long longProduct = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
        System.out.println(intProduct); // Prints 500654080
        System.out.println(longProduct); // Prints 86400000000
   }
}
```

Obviously after the multiplication has overflowed, the division isn't going to "undo" that overflow.

Comment: What does 1000 days * 1000 mean anyway?

Comment: Those must be them new "metric years" they're always talkin' about.

Comment: 1000 days * 1000 would be 1,000,000 days. There's nothing mysterious about that. Now, 1000 inches x 1000 inches is 1,000,000 square inches, so presumably 1000 days x 1000 days would be 1,000,000 square days. But I'm not exactly sure what a "square day" is. Perhaps that's a unit of measure that time travellers use when dealing in pan-dimensional space.

Comment: Days ? 24*60'60*1000*1000 is the nr of microseconds in a day. :)

Comment: i think it would depend on units, whether microseconds in a day or days in metric year?

Answer (score 22):

You need to start with 24L * 60 * ... because the int overflows.

Your question BTW is a copy/paste of **Puzzle 3: Long Division** from [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/contents.html) ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform that calculation, then you must either re-order the operations (to avoid overflow) or use a larger datatype. The real problem is that arithmetic on fixed-size integers in Java is not associative; it's a pain, but there's the trade-off.

Comment: re-ordering the numbers will not avoid the overflow

Comment: @cherouvim, but reordering the operations could.

Comment: I believe Thom is talking about reordering the multiplication so you do something like this instead: ((24 * 60)/(24 * 60)) * ((1000 * 1000)/(1000*1000))

Comment: Fixed size integers are integers modulo a number (a residue class ring), so operations other than division have all the usual good properties (associative, commutative, distributive, ...). This doesn't hold for floating point, though.