# How Java processes for overflow integers

Tags: java, math, integer, overflow, long-integer

Now signed_int max value is 2,147,483,647 i.e. 2^31 and 1 bit is sign bit, so

when I run `long a = 2,147,483,647 + 1;`

It gives `a = -2,147,483,648` as answer.. This hold good.
But, `24*60*60*1000*1000 = 86400000000` (actually)...
In java, `24*60*60*1000*1000 it equals to 500654080`..
I understand that it is because of **overflow** in integer, but what processing made this value come, What logic was used to get that number by **Java**. I also [refered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301375/1758960).

Comment: This should be of interest to you - http://stackoverflow.com/q/12758338/1679863

Comment: think of it that way: `24*60*60*1000*1000 = (((24*60)*60)*1000)*1000` and apply the same rule you did in your addition example.

Comment: @jlordo I want to know how java processes

Comment: @Gru. What process are you interested in? I answered a similar question last year, that I've linked in my previous comment. You can go through it. If still you have any doubt, then you can ask for clarification.

Comment: @RohitJain Similar?  Seems exactly same.  Guess that question originated from Bloch's puzzlers text.

Comment: @devnull. Yeah those are in fact the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication is executed from left to right like this

```
    int x = 24 * 60;    
    x = x * 60;     
    x = x * 1000; 
    x = x * 1000;
```

first 3 operations produce 86400000 which still fits into Integer.MAX_VALUE. But the last operation produces 86400000000 which is 0x141dd76000 in hex. Bytes above 4 are truncated and we get 0x1dd76000. If we print it

```
System.out.println(0x1dd76000);
```

the result will be

```
500654080
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite subtle: when writing `long a = 2147483647 + 1`, the right hand side is computed first using `int`s since you have supplied `int` literals. But that will clock round to a negative (due to overflow) before being converted to a `long`. So the promotion from `int` to `long` is too late for you.

To circumvent this behaviour, you need to promote at least one of the arguments to a long literal by suffixing an L.

This applies to all arithmetic operations using literals (i.e. also your multiplication): you need to promote one of them to a long type.

The fact that your multiplication answer is 500654080 can be seen by looking at

```
long n = 24L*60*60*1000*1000;
long m = n % 4294967296L; /* % is extracting the int part so m is 500654080 
                             n.b. 4294967296L is 2^32 (using OP notation, not XOR). */
```

What's happening here is that you are going 'round and round the clock' with the int type. Yes, you are losing the carry bits but that doesn't matter with multiplication.

Comment: I want to know how 24*60*60*1000*1000 it equals to 500654080, what processing made java come up with this number

Comment: @Gru, I've put the reconciliation in my answer

Comment: your answer was good but @Evgeniy Dorofeev provided step by step analysis, +1 for your answer...Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

As the range of int is **-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647**.
So, when you keep on adding numbers and its exceed the maximum limit it start gain from the left most number i.e. **-2,147,483,648**, as it works as a cycle. That you had already mentioned in your question.

Similarly when you are computing **24*60*60*1000*1000** which should result **86400000000** as per Maths.

But actually what happens is somehow as follows:

**86400000000** can be written as **2147483647+2147483647+2147483647+2147483647+..36 times+500654080**

So, after adding **2147483647** for **40 times** results **0** and then **500654080** is left which ultimately results in **500654080**.

I hope its clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add L in your multiplicatoin. If you add L than it multiply you in Long range otherwise in Integer range which overflow. Try to multiply like this.

```
24L*60*60*1000*1000
```

This give you a right answer.

Comment: I already know this check for the link in question, my question how java processes and gives a result such number.

Answer (score 0):

An Integer is 32 bit long. Lets take for example a number that is 4 bit long for the sake of simplicity.

It's **max** positive value would be:

```
0111 = 7 (first bit is for sign; 0 means positive, 1 means negative)
0000 = 0
```

It's **min** negative value would be:

```
1111 = -8 (first bit is for sign)
1000 = -1
```

Now, if we call this type `fbit`, `fbit_max` is equal to 7.

```
fbit_max + 1 = -8
because bitwise 0111 + 1 = 1111
```

Therefore, the span of `fbit_min` to `fbit_max` is 16. From -8 to 7.

If you would multiply something like `7*10` and store it in `fbit`, the result would be:

```
fbit number = 7 * 10 (actually 70)
fbit number = 7 (to get to from zero to max) + 16 (min to max) + 16 (min to max) + 16 (min to max) + 15 (the rest)
fbit number = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
24*60*60*1000*1000 = 86400000000
```

Using MOD as follows:    86400000000 % 2147483648 = 500654080